# Can a .bat file inside a Hyper-V virtual machine be invoked from the host machine?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v, windows-server-2012, remote-execution

I have a Windows Server 2012 virtual machine in Hyper-V.  I have a .bat file in this VM that I want to call from the host (Windows 10) machine.

Is this possible?

Comment: "Is this possible?" - No; It is not possible.   Place the .bat file on a network share that is accessible to both the host and the guest operating system instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could use psexec, as long as the target machine is on the same network.  That doesn't have anything to do with virtualization though.  It will work on any machine that you have remote access to (subject to access rights and privileges of course).